# How to distinguish between shared mailbox and normal user via graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to distinguish between shared mailbox and normal user via graph api? Right now `/users` endpoint returns shared mailboxes in the same way as unlicensed users and according to docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user there is no way to tell which user is shared mailbox. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since there isn't a difference between a User with a mailbox and a User with a mailbox shared with other users. AAD only handles User entity, Exchange manages the Mailbox entity and sharing permissions attached to that User.